# Paint.setAntiAlias(false) has no effect?

Tags: android, paint, android-canvas, antialiasing

I'm trying to draw text without antialiasing on a canvas in Android. The font I want to use is a file cour.ttf, which I've copied from my PC's C:\windows\fonts directory to my app's assets directory.

I'm using this code:

```
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"cour.ttf"));
paint.setTextSize(20);
paint.setAntiAlias(false);
canvas.drawText("ABCDE abcde 12345 -+/#.",100,100,paint);
```

The setAntiAlias function doesn't appear to have any effect though.
This picture shows my results:
http://oi47.tinypic.com/35253wo.png

The first line is a screenshot from the app, with antialiasing set to false.
The second line is a screenshot from the app with antialiasing set to true.
The third line is what I would expect to get, it's a screenshot made from my PC in notepad.exe with the same font.

Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected output with antialiasing off? What I'm trying to achieve here is to have pixelated unblurred text.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
I haven't quite found the solution yet, but I did find something interesting:
adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` to my Activity cleared it up quite a bit. Apperently this is turned on by default on Android 4. There's still a (very light) shadow visible that I'd like to remove though.

Screenshot with hardware acceleration disabled:
http://oi49.tinypic.com/aayypj.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pixels densities on PC and phone seem to be different, that is why the difference in appearance of text. You can't compare the phone rendered text with the one rendered on your PC. I think the pixel density on your phone is high, so you not able to see the effect of anti-aliasing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The screenshot I made was taken from a tablet (Acer Iconia Tab A200) with an MDPI screen. Its density is higher than a PC, but not so dense I can't make out individual pixels anymore at normal viewing distance.

Comment: Have you set the SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG ? Thats one possibility. Try setting it to false in `Paint`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried it but it doesn't seem to have any effect either (same result for true or false). Does it have any effect when you use it?

Comment: It does make a difference when working font dimensions. Setting to true gives more accurate..

Comment: The subpixel flag gave me new inspiration for google-keywords and I found something interesting about hardware acceleration; I've edited my question. Maybe you have an idea to remove the shadow effect? I've tried paint.setShadowLayer and it doesn't affect test. Anyway I'm rather pleased with the result so far already so for helping me find the solution I'll give you the bounty (in one hour when I can).